# what is meant by rv_frozen object in scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am writing Python script to code for finding probability of Hypergeometric distribution. When I am using `hypergeom()` function in `scipy`, it is showing like below:

```
scipy.stats.distributions.rv_frozen object at 0*2519690
```

I have googled but couldn't find anything useful. I just wanted to know what does it actually mean?

Comment: That's just a string representation of the object you get from the `hypergeom()` function. It tells you its class: `scipy.stats.distributions.rv_frozen` and memory location. So not very informative.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37511417/2087463) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37501076/2087463) contain descriptions and useful info about the `rv_frozen` class.

Answer (score 8):

It's an object (an instance, really) which knows its shape parameters (hypergeom: M, N, n) and has methods pmf, cdf etc. These two are equivalent from a user perspective: `hypergeom.pmf(4, 20, 7, 12)` and `hypergeom(20, 7, 12).pmf(4)`.

See the stats [tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html) and the [hypergeom reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html).

Comment: how about the `johnsonsu` distribution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65640725/scipy-stats-continuous-distributions-attribute-entropy-doesnt-work-manually