# How to get parameter arguments from a frozen spicy.stats distribution?

Tags: python, random, parameters, scipy, distribution

## Frozen Distribution

In [`scipy.stats`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#statistics-scipy-stats) you can create a [*frozen* distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#freezing-a-distribution) that allows the parameterization (shape, location &  scale) of the distribution to be permanently set for that instance.

For example, you can create an gamma distribution ([`scipy.stats.gamma`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html#scipy-stats-gamma)) with `a`,`loc` and `scale` parameters and *freeze* them so they do not have to be passed around every time that distribution is needed.

```
import scipy.stats as stats

# Parameters for this particular gamma distribution
a, loc, scale = 3.14, 5.0, 2.0

# Do something with the general distribution parameterized
print 'gamma stats:', stats.gamma(a, loc=loc, scale=scale).stats()

# Create frozen distribution
rv = stats.gamma(a, loc=loc, scale=scale)

# Do something with the specific, already parameterized, distribution
print 'rv stats   :', rv.stats()
```

---

```
gamma stats: (array(11.280000000000001), array(12.56))
rv stats   : (array(11.280000000000001), array(12.56))
```

### Accessible `rv` parameters?

Since the parameters will most likely not be passed around as a result of this feature, is there a way to get those values back from only the frozen distribution, `rv`, later on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Accessing `rv` frozen parameters

Yes, the parameters used to create a frozen distribution are available within the instance of the distribution. They are stored within the [`args` & `kwds` attribute](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.17.0/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L423-L428). This will be dependent on if the distribution's instance was created with positional arguments or keyword arguments.

```
import scipy.stats as stats

# Parameters for this particular alpha distribution
a, loc, scale = 3.14, 5.0, 2.0

# Create frozen distribution
rv1 = stats.gamma(a, loc, scale)
rv2 = stats.gamma(a, loc=loc, scale=scale)

# Do something with frozen parameters
print 'positional and keyword'
print 'frozen args : {}'.format(rv1.args)
print 'frozen kwds : {}'.format(rv1.kwds)
print
print 'positional only'
print 'frozen args : {}'.format(rv2.args)
print 'frozen kwds : {}'.format(rv2.kwds)
```

---

```
positional and keyword
frozen args : (3.14, 5.0, 2.0)
frozen kwds : {}

positional only
frozen args : (3.14,)
frozen kwds : {'loc': 5.0, 'scale': 2.0}
```

### Bonus: Private method that handles both `args` and `kwds`

There is an private method, [`.dist._parse_args()`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.17.0/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L512), which handles both cases of parameter passing and will return a consistent result.

```
# Get the original parameters regardless of argument type
shape1, loc1, scale1 = rv1.dist._parse_args(*rv1.args, **rv1.kwds)
shape2, loc2, scale2 = rv2.dist._parse_args(*rv2.args, **rv2.kwds)

print 'positional and keyword'
print 'frozen parameters: shape={}, loc={}, scale={}'.format(shape1, loc1, scale1)
print
print 'positional only'
print 'frozen parameters: shape={}, loc={}, scale={}'.format(shape2, loc2, scale2)
```

---

```
positional and keyword
frozen parameters: shape=(3.14,), loc=5.0, scale=2.0

positional only
frozen parameters: shape=(3.14,), loc=5.0, scale=2.0
```

#### Caveat

Granted, using private methods is typically bad practice because technically internal APIs can always change, however, sometimes they provide nice features, [would be easy to re-implement should things change](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/05dc7b8b0662c9c973203b36044458ca35084833/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L548-L550) and [nothing is *really* private in Python :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/551361/2087463).