# How to get the distribution name from a spicy.stats. frozen distribution?

Tags: python, random, scipy, distribution

## Access to a Frozen Distribution's Name

When creating a [*frozen* distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#freezing-a-distribution) from the [`scipy.stats`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#statistics-scipy-stats) package, how can the distribution's name be accessed once the distribution instance is frozen?  Trying to access the `.name` attribute produces an error since it is no longer an attribute of the `rv` variable.

```
import scipy.stats as stats

# Get the name of the distribution
print 'gamma :', stats.norm.name

# Create frozen distribution
rv = stats.norm()

# Get the name of the frozen distribution
print 'rv    :', rv.name
```

---

```
gamma : norm
rv    :

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
      9 
     10 # Get the name of the frozen distribution
---> 11 print 'rv    :', rv.name

 AttributeError: 'rv_frozen' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The Frozen Distribution `rv_frozen` Class

The frozen distribution, or [`rv_frozen` class](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.17.0/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L423-L431) creates an instance of the distribution during initialization and this is stored in the [`self.dist`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.17.0/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L431) attribute. To access attributes of the original distribution, use `rv.dist.{attribute}`.

```
import scipy.stats as stats

# Get the name of the distribution
print 'gamma :', stats.norm.name

# Create frozen distribution
rv = stats.norm()

# Get the name of the frozen distribution
print 'rv    :', rv.dist.name
```

---

```
gamma : norm
rv    : norm
```