# scipy.stats attribute `entropy` for continuous distributions doesn't work manually

Tags: python, entropy, information-theory, probability-distribution, scipy.stats

Each continuous distribution in `scipy.stats` comes with an attribute that calculates its differential entropy: `.entropy`. Unlike the normal distribution (`norm`) and others that have a closed-form solution for entropy, other distributions have to rely on numerical integration.

Trying to find out which function the `.entropy` attribute is calling in those cases, I found a function called `_entropy` in `scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.py` that does so with `integrate.quad(pdf)` (numerical integration).

But when I try to compare the two approaches (the attribute `.entropy`  vs. numerical integration with the function `_entropy`), the function gives an error:

`AttributeError: 'rv_frozen' object has no attribute '_pdf'`

Why does the distribution's attribute `.entropy` calculate fine, but the function `_entropy` gives an error?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate 
from scipy.stats import norm, johnsonsu
from scipy.special import entr

def _entropy(self, *args): #from _distn_infrastructure.py
    def integ(x):
        val = self._pdf(x, *args)
        return entr(val)

    # upper limit is often inf, so suppress warnings when integrating
    # _a, _b = self._get_support(*args)
    _a, _b = -np.inf, np.inf   
    with np.errstate(over='ignore'):
        h = integrate.quad(integ, _a, _b)[0]

    if not np.isnan(h):
        return h
    else:
        # try with different limits if integration problems
        low, upp = self.ppf([1e-10, 1. - 1e-10], *args)
        if np.isinf(_b):
            upper = upp
        else:
            upper = _b
        if np.isinf(_a):
            lower = low
        else:
            lower = _a
    return integrate.quad(integ, lower, upper)[0]
```

Using the attribute works fine:

```
print(johnsonsu(a=2.55,b=2.55).entropy())
```

returns    `0.9503703091220894`

But the function does not:

```
print(_entropy(johnsonsu(a=2.55,b=2.55)))
```

returns **the error** `AttributeError: 'rv_frozen' object has no attribute '_pdf'`, even though `johnsonsu` [*does* have this attribute](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/01df330eb643e00ff3dc006e805a33d50a539892/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L4038):

```
def _pdf(self, x, a, b):
    # johnsonsu.pdf(x, a, b) = b / sqrt(x**2 + 1) *
    #                          phi(a + b * log(x + sqrt(x**2 + 1)))
    x2 = x*x
    trm = _norm_pdf(a + b * np.log(x + np.sqrt(x2+1)))
    return b*1.0/np.sqrt(x2+1.0)*trm
```

Which function is the attribute `.entropy` calling then in the case of the `johnsonsu`?

Answer (score 1):

You want either `johnsonsu(a=2.55,b=2.55).entropy()` if you are using frozen distributions or `johnsonsu.entropy(a=2.55,b=2.55)` otherwise.

The *why* part of your question is basically that leading underscore in _entropy means "implementation detail, don't call directly". A longer answer is that frozen distributions wrap a distribution instance (self.dist), and delegate to it the calls to _pdf, _pmf etc.

EDIT: executing `johnsonsu(a=2.55,b=2.55)` creates a frozen distribution, rv_frozen. Don't do it unless you want to reuse the instance multiple times: just give the a,b shape parameters as arguments to the entropy function.

Comment: so how can I get the manual `_entropy` function to work? and is it really what the attribute `.entropy` is calling? I don't know if I'm using frozen distributions since I don't know what those are. All I thought I was doing was estimating `johnsonsu`. The distinction between frozen and non-frozen is not helped with the two code examples you wrote since they both work just as well as each other